# How to Handle HttpAsyncClient exception

Tags: java, httpclient

I want to understand few basic concepts about HttpAsyncClient .

1. I am not using connection pool here , What is the correct way to close failed http request here (1) or (2) .
2. What are the performance implications here ,if I Initialize httpclient with each new request ?
3. Do I need to close the connection in finally block for all the failed requests , What is the drawback of not doing so ?

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setConnectTimeout(3 * 1000)
    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(3 * 1000)
    .setSocketTimeout(30 * 1000)
    .build(); 

CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
    .build();

httpclient.start();

try {

    if (targetHost != null && httpget != null)
        response = httpclient.execute(HttpHost, HttpGet);
    catch (Exception e) {

        throw new CustomException("service.unavailable");

    } finally {
        if (httpget != null){
            httpget.releaseConnection(); (1)
            httpclient.close();(2)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks OK at first glance. I would get rid of the httpget.releaseConnection(), it is not necessary. Running the close statement will take care of everything you need and also free the thread running the connection. That kind of answers your third question; closing the connection will free the resources attached to it.

As for initializing a new connection each request; I wouldn't be so concerned with resources as the response of the servers/websites you are connecting to with this. Opening any web request takes time not really on your behalf but the server and waiting for responses and things to happen. I would write an optimized function with all of the handling of the web request and call that for each one, as it would open up the door to make this a multi-threaded application where multiple connections can  be established while others are busy.

Comment: Thanks Edward , What if I do not close httpclient connection at all in finally block,A new thread will be created with new request without closing failed connection ? My code works fine if there is no finally block .